# Where can I find all of the keepers?

Tags: mass-effect

At the start of Mass Effect, after your initial meeting with the Council, Ashley notices Chorban, who is crouching next to a keeper using an experimental medical device to scan them. Upon speaking to him he offers to give you the device and in return expects you to scan all of the keepers on the Citadel.

[image: scan the keepers]

How many keepers are there in total and where can I find them all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very good [link](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Scan_the_Keepers) detailing the locations of each keeper;

[image: keeper locations]

I personally had a really hard time finding the last two or three, despite the guide.